# Term for the ending consonant of one word connected/disconnected from the next leading to different yet related meanings?

Tags: terminology

In his 2013 TEDx Houston talk [The tyranny of the rocket equation](https://youtu.be/uWjdnvYok4I?t=648), astronaut and International Space Station Flight Engineer Don Pettit humorously introduces two categories of mass launched from Earth into space:

At about `10:46` in the video:

> So this brings me to my final slide.
>
> The tyranny of the rocket equation; it involves the magnitude of gravity, and the energy in chemical bonds, which hold this tyrannical grip on our ability to even make rockets, and it’s very difficult to even leave Earth, and it’s particularly so to leave Earth with significant payload.
>
> If the magnitude of Earth’s gravity were slightly larger you could reach a point where we couldn’t even get off the planet using rockets.
>
> So the question that I’d like to plant in all of you guys and gals minds is something to do with rethinking rockets. Is there some other way to get off of Earth without using a rocket; hence you could break the tyranny of the rocket equation, or if we’re not clever enough to think of an answer, and we have to use rockets, could we minimize the tyranny simply by **we don’t bring our dumb mass**.

- "smart mass": computers, life-support..
- "dumb mass": (extra) air, water, bricks...

An ongoing question in space exploration is that of the smartness of sending people versus robotic spacecraft to space. And so a twist on astronaut Pettit's last line in his talk would be:

> *we don’t bring our dumb ass*

meaning that all of the air, water, life-support, humans and waste can be avoided. Leave your [dumb-ass](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dumb-ass) on Earth and just send the robot to space, implying it's stupid to send humans to space.

**Question:** What is it called when the ending consonant of one word being connected or disconnected from the next word can lead to two different but related terms?

[image]

Comment: I may need some help with proper tagging.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa+metanalysis

Comment: @tchrist [The process by which the division between words or parts of words is changed, resulting in the creation of a new word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/metanalysis) As far as I can tell, that seems to be *exactly* what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @tchrist I'm never sure what to do with questions answered in comments rather than in answers. Sometimes people may perceive this as "too obvious to be here" and start down-voting. I'm thinking of just deleting this rather than let it attract more down votes.

Comment: I was hoping that some community member would make a proper answer.

Comment: @tchrist okay thanks, I'll keep an eye on it. It's certainly possible someone will have more insight and be able to expand on this a bit.